# How to implement 'domain protection' in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, security, actionscript, flashvars

I want to limit my SWF file so that it cannot be stolen and hosted on another server. So if the domain serving the SWF file isn't on a list of approved domains, the SWF will not load normally but will instead display a message that links to one of the approved locations. What I'm unsure about is how to access the domain that is hosting the file (or get the fully qualified URL of the file). If You know how to get that information, or if you know of a completely different situation to achieve the same result, please post an answer.

I'm using Flash CS4 to compile the code targeting FP 9.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this
http://www.ghostwire.com/blog/archives/as3-domain-locking-swfs/

Answer (score 1):

i'm using this line of code:

var domain = ExternalInterface.call ("eval", "document.domain");